# Is there a way to display all the bounding boxes that i find?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, jupyter-notebook, bounding-box

I have been able to get all the contours in an image I have but I'm unable to print all the bounding boxes for the respective contours.

I tried printing each bounding in the for loop, but that just hangs the program midway:

```
import cv2
img=cv2.imread("C:/Users/user1/example_check.png")

gr=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,th=cv2.threshold(gr,225,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

ca=cv2.Canny(th,225,255)

con,h=cv2.findContours(ca.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

s_con=sorted(con,key=cv2.contourArea,reverse=True)[1:]

for (i,c) in enumerate(s_con):
    dc=cv2.drawContours(img.copy(),s_con,-1,(0,255,0),1)
    cv2.imshow('Contours',dc)

    (x1,y1,w,h)=cv2.boundingRect(c)
    rect=cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y1),(x1+w,y1+h),(0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imshow("Rectangled",rect) 

    if cv2.waitKey(1)==13:
        break

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I expect the output to show me all the existing bounding boxes, but the program hangs upon execution

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are waiting for a keypress each iteration of the `for` loop. It is designed to show one bounding rect per loop, and wait for the keypress until you open a new window.

This is what is causing your program to hang:

```py
    if cv2.waitKey(1)==13:
        break
```

In terms of moving forward, you could do this a couple of ways. First, you could remove the keypress and open a seperate window for each rectangle. Or, you could draw all the rectangles onto one image. I have chosed this path for my following example code:

```py
import cv2
img=cv2.imread("C:/Users/user1/example_check.png")

gr=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,th=cv2.threshold(gr,225,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

ca=cv2.Canny(th,225,255)

con,h=cv2.findContours(ca.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

s_con=sorted(con,key=cv2.contourArea,reverse=True)[1:]

for (i,c) in enumerate(s_con):
    img=cv2.drawContours(img.copy(),s_con,-1,(0,255,0),1)

    (x1,y1,w,h)=cv2.boundingRect(c)
    # instead of creating a new image, I simply modify the old one
    img=cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y1),(x1+w,y1+h),(0,255,0),2)

# show the modified image with all the rectangles at the end.
cv2.imshow("Rectangled",img) 


cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**EDIT**
The same has been done to the contours as the bounding rects. (`dc=` to `img=`).

Comment: Hi Calder, thanks! My program isn't hanging anymore! But the output shows only a single contour point rather than a bounding box/bounding rectangle. You can check the image here - https://imgur.com/a/IlVUAWo

Comment: @Ravichandran I edited my code. I did the same thing for the contours as I did for the bounding rectangles. Try it now.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help again, but the output this time is showing just the cheque, plain and without any contours or bounding boxes. Check it here - https://imgur.com/a/I3FY7vC